# Gradle generateGrammarSource task isn't working

Tags: gradle, antlr4

I want to generate antlr4 lexer using gradle `generateGrammarSource` task.
Path to g4 file is `src/main/antlr4/my/package/mygrammar.g4`
I tried to use some examples I found so `build.gradle` has the following code:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.20'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

group 'my.package'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'antlr'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
    compile group: 'org.antlr', name: 'antlr4', version: '4.7.2'
    testCompile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit:$kotlin_version"
}

generateGrammarSource {
    arguments += ['-package', 'my.package']
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}

compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

Executing `generateGrammarSource` task generates nothing and gives the following output:

```
:generateGrammarSource NO-SOURCE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 0s
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to create directory `src/main/antlr` and add [Kotlin](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/kotlin) grammar files into there. most likely the `my/package/` is the reason why it cannot find the grammar files; while this [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39233091/gradle-antlr4-plugin-in-android-app-build-fails) hints for, to add generated sources to the source-set. see [The ANTLR Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/antlr_plugin.html).

Comment: You are right about the directory, but what are these Kotlin grammar files about? I don't want to parse Kotlin...

Comment: @Okumo just thought it's a `Kotlin` project because of the dependencies.

Comment: It's a Kotlin project, but not every Kotlin project needs to parse Kotlin.